# What is causing the AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values' in my code

Tags: python

I am getting the following error code in Python when I am trying to run a loop through a directory.

```
File "C:/Users/mikes/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/spyder/utils/site/untitled1.py", line 17, in <module>
    for country in rivers.values():    
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'
```

This is my code:

```
rivers = {'nile' : 'egypt', 'ohio' : 'us', 'rhine' : 'germany' }

# prints river name

for rivers in rivers.keys():
    print (rivers)

# prints country
for country in rivers.values():
    print (river)

# prints statement " The (river) is in the country of (country)
for rivers in rivers:
    print ("The " + rivers.keys() + "is in the country of " + rivers.vaules())
```

Answer (score 4):

In the statement `for rivers in rivers.keys():`, you redefine `rivers`: at the end of the loop, it becomes the name of the last key (a string) and does not refer to the dictionary anymore. Solution: use another name for the loop variable.

Answer (score 4):

You have a few things wrong with your code. Your country loop uses the wrong variable name, you redefine rivers (which is what gives you your error), and your print statement won't work anyway

```
rivers = {'nile' : 'egypt', 'ohio' : 'us', 'rhine' : 'germany' }

# prints river name

for river in rivers.keys():
    print (river)

# prints country
for country in rivers.values():
    print (country)

# prints statement " The (river) is in the country of (country)
for river in rivers:
   print ("The " + river + "is in the country of " + rivers[river])
```